# clojure development with fireplace.vim

Tags: vim, clojure

Recently I've been study clojure ,I want to use vim (fireplace.vim) .

but in the fireplace.vim README file ,I don't quite understand "The only external dependency is that you have either a Vim with Python support compiled in, or ruby in your path. (Don't ask.)"

（see https://github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace)

I don't know whether my vim editor is qualified and what does "ruby in your path" mean...
I'm newbie in vim & linux .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only external dependency is that you have either a Vim with Python support compiled in, or ruby in your path.

To check if vim has python support you can do a

```
vim --version | grep python
```

If you see a `+python` vim has been compiled with python support. If you see a `-python` vim has not been compiled with python support.

If vim doesn't support python you can probably reinstall vim with python support through whatever package manager you are using.

---

To see if ruby is in your path you can type `which ruby`. It should come back with the location of the ruby executable.

Path in Linux is where programs search for the location of the executable you want to run. You can see your path by typing `echo $PATH`.

So when you type `ls` in your shell. The shell goes of and searches every directory listed in your path variable for an executable named `ls` and then executes the first one.

Comment: Most if not all vim packages have python and ruby enabled out of the box. If you have to build and install vim from source, as I recently had to on CentOS 5.4, be sure to make with the proper flags to enable those features.